# How to improve JavaScript performance / reduce page load on a page with large HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, huge-pages

We have a page layout as below, with jQuery click handler for a large number of HTML elements (thousands of DIVs).

The layout is like this:

[image]

---

The Navbar contains at least  2000+ DIVs and UL , LI (used for content navigation), and we have jQuery event handler bind to each element:

```
$('.navbar-item').click(function(){ 

  /* click handler */

});
```

It took a lot of times to load, and on IE the performance is terrible !!!
Is there anyway we can improve it ? or any alternative  design to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use on function (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

for example:

```
$('div.navbar').on('click', '.navbar-item', function(){ 

  /* click handler */

});
```

Comment: Simple, click modify dom tree, on do it dynamicly. But on, do not take event click to html object, but only for div.navbar.

Answer (score 2):

You have many possibilities to improve the performances

**`1.`** You can load div just when user scroll and use Ajax

**`2.`** use **[`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** and not **`.click`** to add listener dynamically

For example, you can load some `div` and check the scroll, use this function from [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/), it works on all browsers

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}


$(window).scroll(function() {
       // when the scroll is in bottom
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
           // use ajax to get more div
           $.ajax({
               url: "otherDivs.php", // page where you load div
               data { firstDiv : '10', secondDiv : '20'}, // parameters : To load div 10 to 20
               type: "POST"
           })
           .done(function( html ) {
               $( "body" ).append( html ); // html contain div 10 to 20
           });
       }
   });
```

It's just some ways to help you

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the number of nodes on the page. Load only what the user needs immediately, lazy load when the user scrolls down or opens a navigation level (in case you have a collapsible tree).

Answer (score 0):

If the click handler is the same for more items instead of using:

```
$('.navbar-item').click(function(){ 

    /* click handler */

});
```

you can make this:

```
var functionNav = function(){
    /* click handler */
}

$('.navbar-item').on("click", functionNav)
```

If the functions are similar you can also parametrise a function to make more tasks.